# Forcing target link generated by a js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe on one of my page that included a js widget.
This widget included a dynamic link with a target="_self" attribut. I have no possibility to change this.

Therefore, i'm looking for a solution to force the link to be open in target="_parent" or _blank. A solution to overide the target="_self" that is in the generated link.
I try with  and several js i found on stackoverflow but this doesn't work as the link is generated by the js.

I'm a newbie and doesn't really understand all this things but i hope you may understand my problem.

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot access cross domain iframe content, hopefully

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff.
The main page and the iframe page are on the same domain. This is just the target link that is on an other domain so actually i don't believe this is the problem.
Actually my question concern the possibility to force the target on http://hellenica.fr/test.html

Comment: So you have access to iframe content? If so once the iframe is loaded, and the js script as rendered anchor link, you should be able to change its target attribute. Now it is hard to help you more without seeing any relevant code (in question itself)

Comment: Yes, i have access to the iframe content. The iframe page is http://hellenica.fr/test.html 
Do you want me to copy and code the code of this page?

Comment: It would be better if you just provide this part in question itself: `the link is generated by the js` Which js? Why cannot you change it? If its your domain, why don't you change the script generating link? I see you are taliking about a widget, i'm not really familiar with that so...

Comment: OK. I added the code in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A quick fix could be to delegate click event and set target inside handler: `$(document).on('click', '.js-search-button[target=_self]', function(){ this.target = "_blank"; });` But the widget seems to hanlde settings for that: `t.Settings.newWindow?"_blank":"_self"` So it should just be possible to configure it. I have no time to search for it but i guess there is some DOC regarding it. EDIT: maybe that's not a configurable option

Comment: OK! It works! Thanks A. Wolff!

Answer (score 0):

### Why this isn't possible

Firstly, Iframes have been designed in order to prevent cross-domain scripting attacks. Unless the content is on the same domain as the page accessing it, no changes are possible - even minor ones, as you suggest. This is a security feature, and it is best all-round. Imagine the large scale phishing attacks that would occur if you could clone and modify other pages this easily!

### EDIT

If the content is on your own server, this is slightly easier. Follow the other suggestions in the comments to accomplish this.

### Why this might be possible

However, with the above said, if you're willing to move in to the world of PHP, you can download the entire contents of (some) pages using cURL. This would allow you to display a full web page, with all css and scripts working within a div on your own website, similar to an iframe.

The benefit to this method is that, because the content has been downloaded to your server, and you are serving it yourself, it is editable by javascript, css and any other language. An example of it can be seen below;

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example-webpage.com/file.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch); // This is the html - either display it on it's own page, or shove it in a div (if styling allows)
curl_close($ch);
```

Hopefully, this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Lewis,
Actually, my question wasn't well formulated. The main page and the iframe page are on the same domain. This is just the target link that is on an other domain so this shouldn't be a limit.
My question concern the possibility to force the target="_blank" over the target=3_self3 generated by the javascript.

Comment: If you can manipulate the html in javascript, try `$("a").attr("target", "_blank");`

Comment: This is my problem. I can't edit the html in the javascript... Therefore i need something to force, / to overwrite the target attribute generated.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry not sure I can help you with that then. I hope someone else can. Good luck.